# How to catch if JSON property does not exists when deserializing with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm using `MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,` in order to throw an error when there is a property in the JSON and no corresponding property in my C# class.

That works.

In addition to that, I want it to throw an error when there is a property in my class but not in the JSON.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [`JsonObjectAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) with `ItemRequired` set to [`Required.Always`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute_ItemRequired.htm)..

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
```

For example,Assuming `User Class` is defined as

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class User
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

If you attempt to deserialize a Json without the Age Property, for example

```
var json = @"{
'Name':'John Doe',
}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

You would recieve an `JsonSerializationException`

```
Required property 'Age' not found in JSON. Path ''
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to do it without touching the classes?

Comment: @HristoKolev perhaps [this one](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)?

Comment: One more example https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm